# Receiving data through wifi connection

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I'm trying to make the following work, and wonder if it is possible:

I want to send data from a hardware piece to an android device. Although the hardware only has an Ethernet connection available.

If I were to make an Ethernet connection from the hardware piece to a router, and then communicate from the router to the android device with WiFi, is there any way I could tell the android device, just receive data from the WiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **IP** protocol will allow you to communicate over any `IP` network.

Easiest way to do that is using TCP sockets that uses Server/Client relation to communicate.

I'm guessing you are using a microcontroller (arduino?) if that is the case there are many IP labraries and examples you can look at. 
after writing the server code on the hardware then you can easily use sockets to connect to it from android, here is an example on how to connect android client to TCP server.
[TCP Client tutorial](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html)

Extra links:

- [TCP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) no need to read the implimentation details just understand the concept.
- [Java All about Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) Great overview of socket programming and should get you ready to write effective code on the android side.
- [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) wikipedea article about LANs

Comment: Actually I'm working with a DSP. Thank you for answer. I guess my doubt on whether this was possible or not was due to the fact that I only found information on Wi-Fi direct, which only mentioned communication between two android devices. But by your answer, I deduce there's really no obligation on being two android devices. Anyhow I would appreciate any more links on this.

Comment: I'm connection the DSP to a router, through an Ethernet Connection to the LAN port, and then connection a Samsung Galaxy S3 to the router's Wifi.

Comment: C++ and code composer studio. I am not directly responsible for the DSP, but I was told that it works as a server. Does this seem promising?

Comment: Then you should take a look at their networking APIs and hopefully you can find tutorials on creating a TCP server